# node-http-proxy pathRewrite with url params

Tags: node.js, proxy, node-http-proxy

Is there a convenient way with node-http-proxy to rewrite an entire url including params?

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
module.exports = () => ({
  "customer/:customerId":"customer?id=:customerId"
});
```

So I want that the customerId for example gets rewritten to a url parameter named id.

Is that possible with node-http-proxy or an extension?

Comment: First result of google.. https://gist.github.com/indexzero/9087173

Comment: Yes - i have seen that. Does not solve the issue since it does not support url parameters

Comment: req object does contain params. req.params

Comment: Yes exactly. So this does not solve the issue.
Plz see my code example above. I would like to have something like this.

E.g. rewrite customer/3 -> customer?id=3

Comment: So you would like to have a proxy configuration in one place. Is this what you are asking for? Sorry, it is not very self-explanatory.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-request-proxy

This solves the issue